# Price of virtual servers to do a databases benchamrking

Tags: virtual-machine, benchmarking, remote-server

I want to do a benchmark between databases (MySQL Cluster, HBase and Cassandra) but I don't have a distributed architecture. is there any website that gives the possibility to use servers remotely. I need 8 servers for a period of 1 month. If it's possible, how much does it cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any cloud provider Oracle, Amazon, Google, Microsoft Azure.